# How to use Apple's Accelerate to split an interleaved buffer

Tags: macos, simd, accelerate-framework

I am trying to efficiently split an interleaved buffer (the chroma subsampled plane of an image). I reckon the best way would be to use SIMD instructions, but I can't find anything to do the job in Apple's Accelerate framework. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I know AltiVec had `vec_perm()` that would've done the job handsomely. Or ARM's VUZP for that matter.

This should be compiled for i386 / x86_64.

Comment: If you're going to want the luma values eventually, you should probably  shuffle and store them as well, instead of looping again for that.  I don't know anything about Apple's accelerate framework, but yes, x86 has various shuffles to choose from.  SSSE3 `pshufb` takes a vector as a control input.  I'd recommend searching for existing pixel deinterleave functions if you end up having to do it yourself with `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` AVX2 intrinsics or whatever.

Comment: I need to convert from YUV420 P2 to P3, so luma values stay the same. Thanks for the pointers, I’ll look over them.

Comment: There are some good links in the [SSE tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info), with some generic intro-to-SIMD and SSE intrinsics, as well as detailed reference guides.